# Finding 1941 death record or gravesite for Eli(as) Weinstock in Cernauti

Tags: death-records, jewish, romania, 1940s, grave-marker

I am searching for a death record or gravesite for Eli(as) Weinstock who lived in Cernauti in 1941.

He was a journalist.  He died on Rosh Hashana (Jewish New Year) in Sep 1941 and I know he died on that day because his surviving son told me. He remembers the day because it was Rosh Hashana.

Eli(as) was from a well to do family so he most likely had a burial.  Shortly thereafter his family was deported to Transnistria.

The region was in upheaval during this time period. However since the family was wealthy, had servants, etc, and although there may or may not be a death record, I was looking for any potential gravesite in a Jewish cemetery.

Comment: To clarify, "Cernauti" is the city formerly Cernăuți, Romania, now Chernivtsi, Ukraine? And part of the Ukrainian SSR in the Soviet Union at some point? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernivtsi

Comment: That region was in upheaval during the summer/autumn of 1941, with control changing from Romania to USSR, so (a) burial may have been informal / not recorded or (b) records may have been lost or destroyed.

Comment: In the late summer/fall of 1941 the area was turned over from the Russians to the Romanians and then from Sept-Dec 1941 they evacuated almost all Jews (except for 20,000 exemptions) from Cernauti to Transnistria, mostly on foot.   I have this information directly from his son, who walked most of that way to Transnistria and survived.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications or additional information relevant to your question.

Comment: He died in 1941 - was it a natural death or was he murdered in the Holocaust ?

Comment: He died in 1941 of a sudden heart attack due to stress of Holocaust.

Answer (score 2):

Yad Vashem holds a [testimonial](https://yvng.yadvashem.org/remote/namesfs.yadvashem.org/YADVASHEM///23021040_280_1299/62.jpg?width=700) for one Elias Weinstock murdered in 1941, Chernovits

Quoting:

> Elias Weinschtok was born in Czernowitz, Romania to Shaul and Malka.
> He was a **journalist** and married. Prior to WWII he lived in Czernowitz,
> Romania. During the war he was in Czernowitz, Romania.
>
> Elias was murdered in the Shoah.
>
> This information is based on the records/documents displayed below:
> Last Name First Name  Birth Year  Place of Residence  Source Weinschtok
> Elias Czernowitz, Romania
> Page of Testimony Submitted by [Lina Weinstock](https://yvng.yadvashem.org/index.html?language=en&advancedSearch=true&sln_value=Vinshtok%20Weinstock&sln_type=synonyms&sfn_value=Lina&sfn_type=synonyms)

If this is the individual you are looking for, chances of finding a burial site are virtually none, since Holocaust victims have no individual burial site.

Here is the [link](https://yvng.yadvashem.org/index.html?language=en&s_id=&s_lastName=Weinstock&s_firstName=&s_place=Chernovitz&s_dateOfBirth=&cluster=true) to the search I performed in Yad Vashem's archives. I am sharing a search without the given name purposely, in case other Weinstocks from Chernovitz may be of your interest. Perhaps his relatives.

Comment: Yes Lina provided this testimony, and I knew her.  However I cannot find info on Elias in Cernauti before the war.  He was a well to do, they had a custom built house, maid, chauffeurs, etc.  I was hoping to find more about the family before the Romanians sent them to Transnistria.